# MQTT and AWS ELB : How to make ELB _forget_ to which node a client was previously connected to?

Tags: rabbitmq, mqtt, amazon-elb

I have a cluster of 2 RabbitMQ nodes (each running version 3.6.10 of RabbitMQ with MQTT plugin enabled) and an AWS classic load balancer in front of them. Server and clients exchange MQTT messages.

Clients (apps running on mobile devices and using Eclipse Paho client lib) connect to the load balancer which distributes connections in round-robin fashion.

When I bring down one node, say Node1, all clients that were connected to Node1 get a callback indicating connection to the broker is lost.
These clients try to reconnect but the connection attempt fails indicating the broker is not reachable.
From AWS console I can see that AWS ELB detects that Node1 is down and marks it as "OutOfService".
Connection requests from new clients are routed to the "InService" node Node2; however, connection requests from existing clients that were previously connected to Node1 always fail!

ELB is configured with idle timeout of 180 seconds. Enabling or disabling connection draining in ELB did not make any difference.

Is there any specific configuration to make ELB *forget* that the existing clients were connected to Node1 and allow them to connect to Node2?

Comment: @Whoever_down_voted_this_question: It would be useful if you can add a comment about why this question is down-voted. It can help me to avoid similar down-votes in future!

Answer (score 1):

I tried by adding following HA policy :
rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-mqtt "^mqtt" \ '{"ha-mode":"exactly","ha-params":2,"ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'

With this policy in place, all queues created for MQTT clients were mirrored. Now when Node1 is down, connection attempts from existing client IDs also get routed to the other active node!

This makes me wonder what is the relationship between client IDs from MQTT clients and their connection to broker nodes? I thought mirroring of queues is necessary only to retain and access messages that were not yet acknowledged when the queue master node goes down. But I see that the clients are not even able to establish a connection!